# Throw, Catch exception mistakes

Tags: java

Im confused how throw and catch work,I understand their are several mistakes with this ExceptionDemo. If someone could fix the mistake and clearly state why and how they corrected it without using all the Java jargon words, and use simple terms
Thank you

```
public class ExceptionDemo {

    public static void main( String [] args ) {

        try {
           int number = Integer.parseInt(”123”); 
           if (number > 100) {
                 catch new ArithmeticException(”Check the number”); 
           }
        }
        catch {
           System.out.println(”Cannot convert to int”);
        }
        finally (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(”Always print”);
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you at least identify the mistake(s) you want fixed/explained?

Comment: Did you try compiling it?  Is this homework?

Comment: catch new ArithmeticException(”Check the number”); looks weird. Why are you creating a new exception if you're trying to catch one? Maybe you should throw a new exception instead ;-)

Answer (score 1):

a bit tricky to tell exactly what is needed here. for starters looks like as would need to throw an exception if checking for some sort of valid value. also looks like the catch would need to have the exception handler itself not the finally.

//listing 1 slight re-work original post

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ArithmeticException {

            try {
                int number = Integer.parseInt("123");
                if (number > 100) {
                    // is this what trying to do?
                    //would expect typically would be used to handle 
                    //something like div by zero, etc.
                    throw new ArithmeticException("Check the number");
                }
           }
           //catch exception(s) here
           catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot convert to int:" + e.toString());
           }
           finally  {
                System.out.println("Always print");
           }
        }
    }
```

//listing 2 more typical type thing maybe

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                //int number = Integer.parseInt("A123"); // if un-comment throws generic exception bad input

                int number = 100 / 0; //will throw an "arithmetic" exception
                //
                if (number > 100) {
                   //do something.
                   int x = number++;
                }
            }
            catch (ArithmeticException arithEx){
                System.out.println("An ArithmeticException Occurred:" + arithEx.toString());
            }
           catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("A general exception occurred:" + e.toString());
           }
           finally  {
                 //always gets executed. so is good place to clean up, close connections  etc.
                System.out.println("Always print");
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to hurricane's answer, you cannot catch a new exception. Instead you need to throw it.

```
throw new Exception();
```